# Get links and featured image from a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I am trying to create a custom slider in wordpress and add my own links but I am not able to get the featured image of a post to display. Here is my code that I am working with right now.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=20&orderby=rand&numberposts=6'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

<?php echo '<li>'; ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title();?> 
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'small' );?>
</a>
<?php echo '</li>'; ?>
```

This code works by displaying the links randomly but they never display the featured image of a post. Can someone please help out and let me know what i am doing wrong here...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `$attachment` variable is null. I'd suggest to replace:

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'small' );?>
```

with the following instead:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' );?>
```